# RegEx match exactly 4 digits

Tags: javascript, regex

Ok, i have a regex pattern like this `/^([SW])\w+([0-9]{4})$/`

This pattern should match a string like `SW0001` with `SW`-Prefix and 4 digits.

I thougth `[0-9]{4}` would do the job, but it also matches strings with 5 digits and so on.

Any suggestions on how to get this to work to only match strings with `SW`  and 4 digits?

Comment: Add the `$` anchor. `/^SW\d{4}$/`. It's because of the `\w+` where `\w+` match one or more alphanumeric characters.

Comment: `\w+` matches digits as well. Did you mean to use `/^([SW])[a-zA-Z]*([0-9]{4})$/`?

Comment: Please don't add solutions to question.

Comment: http://www.regexpal.com/ is your friend.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Let's see what the regex `/^([SW])\w+([0-9]{4})$/` match

1. Start with S or W since character class is used
2. One or more alphanumeric character or underscore(`\w` = `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)
3. Four digits

This match more than just `SW0001`.

Use the below regex.

```
/^SW\d{4}$/
```

This regex will match string that starts with `SW` followed by exactly four digits.

Answer (score 30):

in regex,

- `^` means you want to match the start of the string
- `$` means you want to match the end of the string

so if you want to match "SW" + exactly 4 digits you need

```
^SW[0-9]{4}$
```

Answer (score 6):

you can use this code in regex

```
^\d{4}$
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get into regex and match 4 numbers...  You can backslash the periods too.

```
get-childitem | where name -match 'journal.\d{4}.txt'
```